# How should I create app registrations on-demand for my users in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-web, azure-app-registration, azure-oauth

I have a simple ASPNET Core Razor Pages app + ASPNET Core API:

for example the API just has:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi()
```

Razor pages has:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(azureConfig)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(...)
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I have two app registrations to support that, one registration for my UI, and one registration for my API that exposes an API.

[image: Azure App Registrations Blade]

So I would like to roll a UI that my users can use to generate a client for their own uses. In my experience, when I see this feature in other apps I usually see they support client credentials only.

Imagine a UI like this:

[image: Example Web UI for Dynamic Client Registration]

Now imagine code behind like this when you click that "Create new client" button:

```cs
public void CreateClientForUser(CurrentUser currentUser)
{
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

    var requestBody = new Application
    {
        DisplayName = "API Key for " + currentUser.DisplayName,
    };
    var result = await graphClient.Applications.PostAsync(requestBody);

    dbContext.UserApps.Add(new UserApp
    {
        UserId = currentUser.Id,
        AppId = result.AppId
    });
}
```

Finally, imagine in my API I had a OnTokenValidated event handler like this:

```cs
// Untested psudocode
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(
    name: JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    configureOptions: jwtBearerOptions =>
{
    var existingOnTokenValidatedHandler = jwtBearerOptions.Events.OnTokenValidated;
    jwtBearerOptions.Events.OnTokenValidated = async tokenValidatedContext =>
    {
        await existingOnTokenValidatedHandler(tokenValidatedContext);

        var context = tokenValidatedContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<BOIDbContext>();

        var principal = tokenValidatedContext.Principal!;
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity!;

        var objectidentifierClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier";
        var objectIdentifier = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Type == objectidentifierClaimType);

        var appId = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Type == "appId");

        if (appId != "Main RazorPages Web UI")
        {
            // This must be a users access token?
            var usersApp = context.UserApps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AppId == appId);
            if(usersApp is null)
            {
                context.Fail($"No app id found in app-user mapping table.");
                return;
            }

            // Set the user id! Done!
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ApplicationClaimTypes.UserId, usersApp.UserId.ToString()));
        }
    };
});
```

Is this approach OK? On most sites that offer API access, they usually have a UI that lets me generate client credentials clients. Should I be only allowing users to create an interactive client? If I did that, the access tokens for my API would not require me to maintain a user mapping table correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can asssign set the user as owner and move such mapping from the db. You can use the [Add owner operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for that. If you want to verify if a user is owner of an application you can use the [List ownedObjects opearation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-ownedobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Regarding the credentials provided, that depends on their needs. If they want an SPA or public app no client credentials are required. But they are needed them if they want a web app or api. The best would be to generate a certificate so that it can be downloaded by the user and registered in the application.  For the latter you can use the [application: addKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addkey?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) operation.

Since you're abstracting app registration and for non social user accounts (they don't have access anyways) it may make sense to [block acces to the Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#restrict-member-users-default-permissions), or [disable app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/delegate-app-roles#restrict-who-can-create-applications) for those users and make your api create the app registrations using [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-client-assertions).